# Using :label that corresponds to %[word]% for LIKE possible in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT id, title, file_name, file_path 
FROM Image 
WHERE title LIKE :search
```

The pdo sql request is prepared like this:

```
//$search is "karen"
$param = "%$search%":
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$executed = $stmt->execute(array(':search' => $param));
if(!$executed){
  $error['error'] = $stmt->errorInfo();
  echo json_encode($error);
  exit();
}
```

My question is, will `%karen%` be interpreted as sql (where `%karen%` means 0 or more characters before the `karen` and 0 or more characters after the `karen`) or will this be literally interpreted as me searching for a title that has `%karen%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `concat` to append `%` and pass the parameter directly:

```
SELECT id, title, file_name, file_path 
FROM Image 
WHERE title LIKE concat('%', :search, '%')
```

Comment: is `concat` smtg understood  by sql? Also since I'm putting this into an array in php can I do `'SELECT id, title, file_name, file_path FROM Image WHERE title LIKE concat('%', :search, '%')'` or do I have to use `''` (double quotes) (ie `"SELECT id, title, file_name, file_path FROM Image WHERE title LIKE concat('%', :search, '%')"`)?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @15ongm - concat is a MySQL function. About the single or double quotes, I am not an expert in php. Perhaps someone else will answer your question.

Comment: @GurV actually I figure out my own question, but thanks for answering my question! This works!